# Implementation of Collaborative Filtering in python

Tags: python, recommendation-engine, collaborative-filtering

I am student of Post graduation. I am doing research on Collaborative Recommendation System. My main focus is to implement item-based and user-based algorithms in python for product dataset. I had gone through few codes which are available on internet but none of them provide apropriate result. So please suggest me some accurate python code with dataset.

Thank You

Comment: Sorry asking for recommendations for libraries/code is off topic for SO, you could just buy/loan the book http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596529321.do which has a section on collaborative filtering

Comment: I may misunderstand something, but does "going through a few codes which are available on internet" really qualify as research these days?